# How to run a script at logon/logoff of one specific user in Windows 10 without using GPO?

Tags: windows-10, script, network-shares, login, logoff

I have a set of computers which are used by several users. One one of those computers I need to map a drive for two users (and only for those two users).

My idea was to run a script on logon of either user to net use the drive, and to run a script on logoff to net use /d the drive, but I can't seem to find a way to set a script at logon/logoff of a specific user.

How can I accomplish this?

Also, I do not want to push this via policies, as that would mean creating an additional policy for this particular computer, which I want to avoid.

Thanks!

PS: obviously only those two users have access to the contents of the mapped share, but I would like the other users to not even know this share exists.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Windows Task Scheduler, as administrator.

It allows you to trigger a task on log on/off, and for all or a specific user.

This task would run your .cmd file(s) which runs I guess "net use"...

If you wish to hide this, you can simply disallow Task Managers to other accounts than you:

https://www.guidingtech.com/disable-task-manager-for-specific-users-in-windows/

Of course, also hide the .cmd file(s) - with attributes *system hidden read-only* for instance, and somewhere in a windows sub folder.